# Excel VBA web scraping - Target a different Frame

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, frames

I want to pull some data off a website and put it into excel.  I have done this before & have the code written that logs me in and browses to the page I want.

At this point though, the website is in a different format. The page I want has frames. The top frame has a banner and some text, and then there is a form in the bottom frame. When i browse to this point in my VBA code, it seems to find the top frame only - no forms etc. How do I specifically target the frame with the form??

The HTML Source Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../custom/LeftSideSquareTabs.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../include/JSCommon.js"></script>

<Script language="JavaScript">
function Dummmy()
{
parent.location.replace('../login.asp?Locale=EN&Lo=1')
}
</script>
</head>


<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" topmargin="0" leftmargin="10"> 

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="786">

        <tr>
            <td width="50%" align="left" height="62"></td>
            <td width="50%" align="right" height="62">


                <a href="http://www.website.com" target="_blank">
                <img name="ToolbarRightLogo" src="../custom/ToolbarlogoRight.gif"  border="0" alt="MMIA version 5.1.0">
                </a>
            </td>

        </tr>

    </table>

<table width="786" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="TabsOff" onclick="dispayMen();">Option A</td>
    <td class="TabsImage"><img src="../images/TabOff.gif" width="4" height="17"></td>
    <td><img src="../images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>
    <td class="TabsOn">Option B<</td>
    <td class="TabsImage"><img src="../images/TabOn.gif" width="4" height="17"></td>
    <td><img src="../images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>
    <td><img src="../images/spacer.gif" width="466" height="1" WIDTH="1" HEIGHT="1"></td>
    <td class="SupportOff" onMouseOver="this.className='SupportOver'" onMouseOut="this.className='SupportOff'" onclick="LogOutSession()">Log out</td>
    <a href="mailto:support@xxxxx.com"><td class="Support" onMouseOver="this.className='SupportO'" onMouseOut="this.className='Support'">Contact</td></a>
    <td><img src="../images/spacer.gif" width="10" height="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td class="TabsOffBottom" colspan="2"><img src="../images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>
    <td class="TabsOnBottom" colspan="3"><img src="../images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>
    <td class="TabsOffBottom" colspan="7"><img src="../images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="TabsOnBottom" width="786" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr> 
    <td class="TabsOffBottom"><img src="../images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>
    <td><img src="../images/spacer.gif" width="9" height="8"></td>
    <td class="MiddleToolbarText" width="526">Option B</td>
    <td class="MiddleToolbarRightText" width="185">Updated to:&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="MiddleToolbarText" width="55">11-02-2015</td>
    <td><img src="../images/spacer.gif" width="9" height="1"></td>
    <td class="TabsOffBottom"><img src="../images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="TabsOnBottom" width="786" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr> 
    <td class="TabsOffBottom"><img src="../images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>'
```

Comment: Without the HTML source is almost impossible to answer this question, please add it.

Comment: I have added the source code of the page that is being scraped. This code doesnt contain the data that i wish to scrap though. "Option B" seems to be option I need....I can see data on screen, but just not in that source code.

Comment: There are no frames in the above HTML.

Answer (score 2):

This simple solution did the trick. (By trial and error, I figured out the frame I wanted to manipulate for Frame 1).

```
Set ieDoc = doc.frames(1).document
```

Comment: can you explain this further please? i have posted a question about this and have had no success